# How would I write this VB.Net loop functionally?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a VB.Net function that translates a `NameValueColletion` to an `IDictionary`. How would I write this functionally (with `Select`, etc. instead of a loop)?

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToDictionary(ByVal source As NameValueCollection)
        As IDictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim ret = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim keys = source.Keys
    For Each key In keys
        Dim sKey = TryCast(key, String)
        Dim sVal = TryCast(source(key), String)
        If sKey Is Nothing OrElse sVal Is Nothing Then Continue For
        ret(sKey) = sVal
    Next
    Return ret
End Function
```

Comment: Just FYI, I am doing this in order to call a method through WCF, since NameValueCollection is not serializable but IDictionary is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Return source.Cast(Of String)().
             ToDictionary(Function(key) key, Function(key) source(key))
```

Comment: Will the `Cast` throw an exception if there are any non-strings?  I don't want that.

Comment: @JoelFan: `Cast()` is running on the keys (that's what NameValueCollection's enumerator returns), which can only be strings.  It's only necessary because NameValueCollection doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Beautiful!  I saw some functional code to do this in C# but I could not manage to translate it to VB.Net.  The auto-translation sites I tried could not handle it.

Comment: FYI I edited your answer to break the line after the period instead of before, as VB.Net does not like it the other way

Comment: It seems to be returning a dictionary of strings without that.  I'm leaving the function declaration the same as in my question: As IDictionary(Of String, String).  Perhaps VB.Net is automatically doing the casting when returning from the function?

Comment: The answer provided by @JoelFan works flawlessly but I don't still quite understand it. This is how I would have done it: `Return (From v In original Select New With {.Key = v, .Value = original(v)}).ToDictionary(Function(k) k.Key, Function(k) k.Value)`

Comment: @JoelFan: You're right; I didn't realize that `NameValueCollection.Item()` is declared as returning `String`.

Comment: @xfx: Why don't you understand it?

Comment: @SLaks: Well, the part that bothers me is `source.Cast(Of String)()`... but I'll run some tests tomorrow (and read some documentation) and see if I can wrap my heard around it ;)

Comment: @xfx: All LINQ methods (except `Cast<>()` and `OfType<>()`) extend `IEnumerable<T>`.  Since `NameValueCollection` only implements `IEnumerable`, you need to call `Cast<>()` to generic-ize it.  (`Cast<>()` returns a generic wrapper enumerable)

Comment: @SLaks: Oh, I see... that's quite interesting. I'll be definitely reading more about it. Thanks!